# When will a memory write become globally visible?

Tags: c, memory, synchronization, x86-64, consistency

I'm writting some low-level synchronization code in C. And I met a problem:

Assume there're two threads `Thread A` and `Thread B` running on a x86_64 machine. `Thread A` write a memory location at time **t1** and there is no more writes to this location afterward. `Thread B` read the same memory location at time **t2**.

```
Thread A:
    foo = magic_value;  /* happens at t1 */

Thread B:
    bar = foo;  /* happens at t2 */
    assert(bar == magic_value);
```

My question is: whether there exist a **delta**, 
for any **t1** and **t2** that **t2 - t1 > delta**. `Thread B` is guarented to read the newest value that `Thread A` wrote at **t1**.

I've read the documents from Intel and AMD and they did not mentioned if such a guarentee exists. I know that this value may depends on processor model or even mother board design (for multi-socket machine). I guess there must be some limit on this latency on any sane currently available x86_64 machine.

**I know how to use sychronization primitives such as locks or memory barriers to guarentee such behaviour.** I just need to know if such a guarenteed latency existed for a memory access to become globally visible.

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: If in case the processor supports out of order execution, then there is a possibility that if the data write takes too much time it will start executing instruction below. I have faced this problem while running my multi-thread code in arm. ARM recommends the usage of memory barrier instructions. http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.faqs/ka14041.html. I did not experience this scenario in x86

Comment: @ram Memory barriers are the exact things I want to avoid here. So I guess if Thread B can wait for a enough time before read, it can always get the newest value.

Comment: I wonder if there is a way to determine that "enough time" you are mentioning. The time for memory update to take place is random unless you place a memory barrier instruction. Putting a sleep() in thread B and assuming that memory update has taken place is not encouraged.

Comment: @ram I have written a very tricky program to detect such "enough time". But there is no soundness guarantee of this program. The longer  it runs, the more accurate it would be. For my 40-core Intel machine this time could be longer than 5000 cycles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure that there are no guarantees about the maximum time between one CPU writing to a memory location and another seeing it. In a NUMA system the coherency protocol will take a long time. In practice it will be as fast as possible, but I doubt there are any guarantees.

Why do you need to know this though? When you're writing synchronization primitives you only need to think about ordering. x86_64 enforces strong consistency which means that stores will be seen by other CPUs in the order they happened and that's really the only thing you need to worry about.

Comment: I am doing some reaserch projects related to performance. It is crucial to know if there is such a worst case latency for a specific machine. I've done experiments on some NUMA systems with tens of cores but it seems there always be a maximum time. I'm just not sure if there exist some rare corner cases that a message would take a indefinite long time.

Comment: I've read CPU documentation for years for different CPUs and I've never seen a latency guarantee. I doubt even the CPU designers know considering how complex the interactions on the memory bus are. Add DMA to the equation, TLB processing, etc. and it could take a long time. As an anecdote: I played around with zeroing memory in the idle loop in an operating system. When testing it disk operations became measurably slower because (I assume) DMA got blocked fighting for the same cache lines as the CPU. And this was on a simple single CPU machine.

Comment: For your experiment I think it's not related to cache since DMA buffers are designed to be non-cacheable on most OSs. ;) But considering in hardware every message queues' sizes  is limited so I think it may be not possible for a message to be delayed for a  indefinite long time.

Comment: On x86 and x86_64 DMA is cache coherent with normal mappings of the memory and this was on an i386 machine.

Comment: Actually, let me expand that and make it stronger. DMA on x86_64 has to be cache coherent *and* mapped cacheable by the OS if there are any other cacheable mappings of the same memory (like `mmap` for example) because of an errata on some AMD cpus where speculative execution could speculatively mark unmodified cache lines dirty which when flushed would overwrite contents of uncached mappings of the same pages. And this just adds to the "no guarantees" problem. Speculative execution is another thing that causes memory bus traffic.

Comment: @Naruil Out of curiosity I was looking for the errata I mentioned, I couldn't find it, but the reading was actually useful for answering your question. Read http://support.amd.com/us/Processor_TechDocs/25759.pdf there are multiple bugs in the cpus where dirty cache lines will never get flushed. Those are bugs of course, but they give you a good idea what conditions could cause writes to get delayed for a long long time. In that document: 66, 81, 92, 106 (fun one), 112.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there exist such delta: The x86 memory is coherent, but I don't think there is any gurarantee on the actual maximum delta. The paper [Comparing Cache Architectures and Coherency
Protocols on x86-64 Multicore SMP Systems](http://people.freebsd.org/~lstewart/articles/cache-performance-x86-2009.pdf) may interest you (although it's a benchmark, not a formal documentation).

AFAIK `foo` should be declared `volatile` to force the compiler to actually add the write instructions instead of optimizing it away.

Comment: On a large NUMA machine a cache coherence message may need to be relayed by many other processors and travel a long way through many circuits. I am curious that if there is a soundness guarentee that for a specific machine such message passing do have a worst-case latency.

Comment: Seems to be an interesting paper. But as you said it's just a benchmark.

Comment: can delta be infinite under x86_64?